# ASP.net MVC - Custom HandleError Filter - Specify View based on Exception Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am inheriting the `HandleErrorAttribute` in my MVC application so I can log the error:

```
public class HandleAndLogErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        if( filterContext.Exception != null )
        {
            // log here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding this as a global filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleAndLogErrorAttribute());
}
```

Is it possible to specify a custom view for specific exception types as well? For example:

```
if( filterContext.Exception is DivideByZeroException )
{
    // how do i specify that the view should be DivideByZero?
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

1. Create a new filter which inherits `HandleErrorAttribute` (or implements IExceptionFilter directly)
2. Register it in global.asax (by replacing `filters.Add(new HandleError());`):

Here is a filter that I've created that tries to find a view per specific HTTP status code:

```
public class MyErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            return;

        var statusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
        {
            statusCode = filterContext.Exception.As<HttpException>().GetHttpCode();
        }
        else if (filterContext.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            //to prevent login prompt in IIS
            // which will appear when returning 401.
            statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden; 
        }
        _logger.Error("Uncaught exception", filterContext.Exception);

        var result = CreateActionResult(filterContext, statusCode);
        filterContext.Result = result;

        // Prepare the response code.
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }

    protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ExceptionContext filterContext, int statusCode)
    {
        var ctx = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, filterContext.Controller);
        var statusCodeName = ((HttpStatusCode) statusCode).ToString();

        var viewName = SelectFirstView(ctx,
                                       "~/Views/Error/{0}.cshtml".FormatWith(statusCodeName),
                                       "~/Views/Error/General.cshtml",
                                       statusCodeName,
                                       "Error");

        var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
        var result = new ViewResult
                         {
                             ViewName = viewName,
                             ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                         };
        result.ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
        return result;
    }

    protected string SelectFirstView(ControllerContext ctx, params string[] viewNames)
    {
        return viewNames.First(view => ViewExists(ctx, view));
    }

    protected bool ViewExists(ControllerContext ctx, string name)
    {
        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ctx, name, null);
        return result.View != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which HTTP Status Codes does this handle? I was under the impression that 404 would never get caught by an Error Filter, and that you need to use <customErrors> to trap those.

Comment: all that are generated through the HttpException.

Comment: Nice solution - I especially like that it retains information about the offending Controller and Action. Tx!

Comment: You said "1. Create a new filter which inherits HandleErrorAttribute", but that's not what you did in your example.

Comment: @notfed: I implemented `IExceptionFilter` instead which also `HandleErrorAttribute`

Comment: I'm not trying to insult or argue, I just think you should edit your post, because technically you're not inheriting from `HandleErrorAttribute`.  `IExceptionFilter` does not inherit from `HandleErrorAttribute`

Comment: What extensions class are you referencing when casting to an HttpException?

Comment: Thanks! Just a note, when trying to implement your snippet, it complained about using the as operator since it didn't have a class type constraint.

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks, but although this approach is working properly, there is not enough information in filterContext to return to the View as an meaningful message or exception type i.e. "database constraint error, etc." How to obtain exception type from **filterContext**?

Comment: @binary: It's in the sample code: `filterContext.Exception`

Comment: Thanks, I find it. There is also Error or Exception number that I use in order to identify the exception but boxing (cast) needed in order to obtain this value. So, could you please a line of code to obtain the exception or error number?