# custom exception in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am implementing the custom exception filter overriding the IExceptionFilter. I would like to return a view(error.cshtml) with the exception details along with the controller and action name.

My current working code:

**Controller:**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StudentVM studentvm)
    {

            try
            {
                studentvm.IsValid = ModelState.IsValid;

                int z = 0;

                int x = 5 / z;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){ return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Student", "Index"));
            }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

<div class="panel panel-primary panel-danger" style="margin-top:50px">

    <div class="panel panel-heading">

        <div class="panel-title">
            <h2> Exception Occured</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" panel-collapse panel-body panel-danger">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <h5 class="text-danger">Error Description : @Model.Exception.Message</h5>

                <h5 class="text-danger">An Error occurred while processing the request.</h5>

            </div>

        </div>



    </div>

    <div class=" panel-footer panel-danger" style="background-color:#eed4d5">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back", @Model.ActionName, @Model.ControllerName, new { @class = "btn btn-small btn-danger" })

    </div>





</div>
```

This part is working fine. I am not sure how to return to the error view using IException filter.

I tried the following:

```
public class StudentExceptionFilter:FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        void IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {


            //var result = new ViewPage("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception,
        //                                                    filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
        //                                                    filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        //                                                    ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153561/3082296

Comment: have you seen this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0ef46a/exception-filters-in-mvc/