# Log all handles exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, logging

How can I log all **handled exceptions**?

I want that whenever I catch an exception I should be able to log it

I want it to work globally and not that i should have to write it each time I catch

I tried subscribing to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` and it did work but I did not have the full stack trace and it called multiple times for each exception (I don't know why)

I also tried wrapping my controller with `ActionFilterAttribute` like below and it worked on all exception from the **controller only** and not if the exception was caught in a service that was called from the controller

```
 public class ExceptionLoggingHandler : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Exception !=null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        }
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: If code catches and handles an exception you can't expect another block of code to then know that this happened. What about external libraries that you use (there are likely many of them including the mvc framework) that handle exceptions as part of those internal routines? Would you now expect to know about all exceptions that were handled there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, you can add your filter as a global filter in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method inside `FilterConfig.cs`. It should then catch all exceptions in all controller actions, and in any methods called from those actions - unless of course those methods already have catch blocks inside them which swallow the exception. In that case the caught exception (unless it's then re-thrown) will inevitably go undetected higher up the stack, which is, naturally, the whole point of catching exceptions.

e.g.

```
public class FilterConfig
{ 
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) { 
       filters.Add(new ExceptionLoggingHandler()); 
    } 
}
```

Also, your attribute should inherit from `HandleErrorAttribute`, not `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Something like this:

```
public class ExceptionLoggingHandler : HandleErrorAttribute 
{

    public ExceptionLoggingHandler() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(context.Exception.Message);
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        //.... continue to produce a suitable response
    }
}
```

(In the .... area you can continue to develop the handler to log more sophisticated data, and return a suitable response, perhaps along the lines of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153561/5947043) (other examples are also available online.)